# If Statements not working in public function? [Swift 3.0 - Xcode]

Tags: swift, xcode, function, if-statement, public

Im trying to sort out my data by putting on conditions, so I can present it in a table. My condition is that `AllData.count` must be equal to 4. And even when it is equal to 4, my data doesn't get append to my new array?
Can anyone tell me whats going wrong?

```
var AllData = [String]()
var DataTable = [String]()

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if AllData.count == 4 {
        DataTable.append(contentsOf: AllData)
        print("appended")
    }

    for i in stride(from: 0, to: DataTable.count - 1, by: 4) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = DataTable[i]
    }

    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad(){
    print("AllData count ------->",AllData.count)
    print("Datatable count---------->",DataTable.count)
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

output:
AllData count -------> 4
Datatable count----------> 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you cannot see anything on your tableview, check if set delegate and data source correctly in `viewDidLoad`. Like this

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

`viewDidLoad` finished before `cellForRowAt`. So the log `AllData count -------> 4 Datatable count----------> 0` seems correct.

However, something is wrong with your `cellForRowAt`. You are saying that, if there are four element in `AllData` which is true, append everything in `AllData` into `DataTable`. Then loop though `DataTable` and assign value to your `UILabel` ? In this way, your label will only have data from the last element of `DataTable`. Moreover, `cellForRow` get called every time a cell is prepared. So say for the second cell, you `DataTable` will have same data in `AllData` twice, and with your loop, you are still assigning the last one to the label. So with no more code, you are displaying a table view will label on each cell displaying the last element from your `AllData` array

Comment: `AllData` is an array containing sorted variables from functions in other VCs, and the first entry and every 5th entry (hence stride of 4) are all the titles I want presented in the table. So I want it to be that every time all the functions are run (so AllData contains all 4 values), these variables are appended to the `DataTable` and have the appropriate title displayed in the table. And then when all the functions are run again and I get 4 more values, another title is displayed in the table. I do understand what your saying, but I cant get anything displayed on my table.

Comment: @Dan.code Check my updated answer. Don't forget to set data source and delegate :/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `cellForRowAt:indexPath` is only called when cells are being `dequeued` so your logic is only ever fired when the screen is first loaded or when you're scrolling through the `tableView`. Instead what you want to do is create a `func updateDataSource()` which is called every time `AllData` is `appended` to. You will also have to call `tableView:insertRowAtIndexPath` inside ur for loop if ur updating the `tableViewDataSource` this will add new cells to ur `tableView`. If that doesn't work just call `tableView.reloadData()`